# Best way to chain @Exceptionhandler from PUT method Handler?

Tags: spring, http

I'm implementing Exception handling.

The PUT controller method is,

```java
// ReservationApiController.java

@RestController
@RequestMapping(UriInfo.API_RESERVATION)
@Validated
public class ReservationApiController {

    @PutMapping(UriInfo.API_RESERVATION_CANCEL)
    public ReservationResponse removeReservations(
            @PathVariable @Positive int reservationInfoId) {
        
        if (!reservationInfoService.isReservationInfo(reservationInfoId)) {
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException("No reservationInfo with the id is found.");
        }
        
        return reservationInfoService.cancel(reservationInfoId);
    }
...
```

and there is the current code. What I want to do is 400 Bad response,

```java
// GlobalExceptionHandler.java

@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionController {

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ExceptionHandler({ ConstraintViolationException.class, ... })
    public ModelAndView handleDisplayInfoNotFound(Exception e) {
        logger.error("data is not valid.", e);

        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.setViewName("error");
        mav.addObject("msg", "유효하지 않은 요청입니다.");

        return mav;
    }
```

Putting a negative value in the path variable results in the following exception, the exception is what I expected.

```
2020-08-11 14:42:24.699 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] ERROR org.edwith.reservation.controller.page.GlobalExceptionController.handleDisplayInfoNotFound(28) - data is not valid.
javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: removeReservations.reservationInfoId: 0보다 커야 합니다
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor.invoke(MethodValidationInterceptor.java:109) ~[spring-context-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689) ~[spring-aop-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.edwith.reservation.controller.api.ReservationApiController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$84c5b6e0.removeReservations(<generated>) ~[classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:871) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) [spring-webmvc-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) [spring-webmvc-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978) [spring-webmvc-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:892) [spring-webmvc-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:663) [servlet-api.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855) [spring-webmvc-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) [servlet-api.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [catalina.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-websocket.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [catalina.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [catalina.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [catalina.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [catalina.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [catalina.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:688) [catalina.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [catalina.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [catalina.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1594) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.33]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_251]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_251]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:9.0.33]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_251]
```

#### Problem

Unlike what I wanted, Response code is **405 with default tomcat error page**. and there is an error msg like that: PUT method doesn't support JSP... (I can't attach it here because it is in korean language)

1. How can I implement the exception handling I want?
2. Is it good to return a HTML format response from the Rest Controller? Or what form of answer would be good to return?

Thank you for reading!

Comment: Return HTML for a REST controller is a bit silly. How would the client interpret that? Instead send an error code (or identified error response to the client).

Comment: @M.Deinum The client uses it as JSOIN if the response code is 2xx and does not use the data if it is a failure code. Well, is it better to just include the error description text in the response body? (not error html page)

Comment: You have a non HTML client, what should it do with HTML?

Comment: @M.Deinum you are right. The reason why I returned html is that the page controller and the rest controller used the same Exception Handler in the same file. Thanks to your comments, the two controller types not use different exception handlers and the rest controller just send error messages. (and in the upper my comment, JSOIN is JSON)